# "Dell Support Center has stopped working" error

Tags: windows-7, laptop

> Dell Support Center has stopped working

I get this message constantly, it pops up like every 20-30 minutes and I can't open Dell Support Center.

Before, it was working okay, but I remember one time it wanted to do some scan on my computer and I was leaving and I just turned it off, maybe that's the cause?

How can I fix it?

EDIT
Couldn't restore using System Restore

[image]

I don't know how to absolutely turn off antivirus, I use Avira and I deactivated AntiVir Guard, I don't know if it's enough

Comment: In my experience, Avira and AntiVir are horrible resource hogs. I actually still wonder if it's just a clever scare-ware operation

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling Dell Support Center again, delete anything else that may be in its original install directory (you have to look, but it is probably in c:\Program files), then run CCleaner's registry cleaner.

I also agree with running `chkdsk /f` (I would run it 2-3 times though).

http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try Windows 7's in-built [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/system-restore) to go back to a point in time before the problem arose (i.e.: before you ran that 'scan').

> System Restore can return your PC's system files and programs to a time when everything was working fine, potentially preventing hours of troubleshooting headaches. It won't affect your documents, pictures, or other data.
>
> Open System Restore by clicking the Start button. In the search box, type System Restore, and then, in the list of results, click System Restore.

You could also probably just [reinstall or uninstall the Dell Support Centre](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/w/microsoft_os/uninstall-dell-support-center.aspx).

Comment: edited about System Restore

Comment: @Templar: I think you've got bigger problems than Dell's Support Centre then. :)  Did you try reinstalling the Dell Support Centre?

Comment: yes I uninstalled it, but I can't install it again, because during instalation at the end I get same error Dell Support Center has stopped working

Comment: @Templar: Then that leads me back to "I think you've got bigger problems than Dell's Support Centre then".  Start doing file-system, disk and RAM tests. If those all come up clean then install a fresh copy of Windows and see how it runs. Otherwise, we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: also wanted to check disk for errors so went to my computer right click properties tools error-checking clicked check now and it says Windows can't check the disk while it's in use and asks me to schedule it, is it normal? because I think I remember it worked fine some time ago

Comment: Any further questions should be posed as new ones.  But I will say, if you are trying to do a write-enabled disk check (chkdsk with /F or /R) on your system drive (usually `C:`) then you _have to_ schedule it for the next reboot; so yes, it's normal. :)

Comment: @techie007 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/945/discussion-between-templar-and-techie007)

Comment: yeah i did disk check and windows memory diagnostic, but I am not sure how it ended because I was afk, and also I have read that results about windows memory diagnostic will be announced when i logon to my account, but I didn't get anything